# properties for lots of images in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I am creating a bus seats layout to show the available seats and user can select a seat to book the same.Since the layout is same most of the time and i do want to support all the screen sizes. I have done the following.

1. Drag and dropped imageViews for each seat
2. Enabled autolayout
3. Added some lots and lots of constraints to make the seat layout look same in all the screen sizes
4. I have 3 images in project folder. which are available seats,booked seats and for some place holders like driver seat
5. created property for all the imageViews and whenever the view loads adding all the seats variable properties to an array for reference.
6. Added a tap recogniser to all the imageViews

The problem is a bus can have 42 seats maximum. So ended up creating 42 imageViews in a grid type. and 42 property variables. The layout may change in future so i want to avoid many properties and am afraid of crashing. Is there any other way to achieve the same? Will Apple accept that in app store because am using lots of imagesViews which may have less then 44px?

Followings are the different ways till now i have tried.

- Dynamically added buttons to view for each seats and populating based on some condition. But i can't add auto layouts in this way because it is fully using code and not at all using storyboards.
- Dragged buttons into scroll view and added a button image for seats fully using storyboards. Since the size of the button is less then 44px for some place holders and seats i don't want this method as apple will reject this anyway.

Targeted for all the screen sizes and from iOS 7 to latest available iOS (means as of now 8.1)

Comment: if this question is not belongs to this forum please let me know by adding comment so that i can remove it also in that case guide me where i can ask. Thanks in advance

Comment: why dont you use uitableview or uicollectionview as they are beneficial for grid based layouts.

Comment: CollectionView would seem the logical choice, implementing your own flowLayout will give you the best control

Comment: you both are suggesting UICollectionView with imageView as cells. What if i want to have a space between 2nd column and 4th column (or kind of pre defined spaces between particular cells) i guess it is possible with custom flowLayout but how much hard is that?

Comment: Even with the default flow layout you can easily have a layout with say 4 seats with two on either side of the aisle. Just use 2 cells per row, each with two image views in them, and give whatever inter-item spacing you want to make the space between the two cells. You could design different cells with 1, 2, or 3 image views in them, and dequeue the ones you need depending on your seat layout for a particular bus.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for the quick response. i don't really have much experience on custom flow layouts. So as per your suggestion ill try default layout with inter-item spacing.

Comment: @rdelmar your suggestion worked. Please answer it so that i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rdelmar suggestion worked very well. So am giving the answer for the future readers.

- For Seat Layout use collection view with custom cell and with default flow layout.
- In my case i have used for 4 seats with two on either side of the aisle. Used 2 cells per row and each cell with two seats (UIImageViews)
- created a NSArray of NSDicitonary to hold the details about the seat numbers and based on the array populating the collection view
- To give a space or align the cell to my need (In my case i need space between place holders like driver seat ,exit) i have used collection view delegate.

  > - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  >     sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

based on the indexPath.row changing my heights between the cells.

Note there is lots of ways we can achieve this layout. I guess collection view with default layout is simple and very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int maxElements = (int) SeatArray.count;         // Number of elements
    int xMarge = 10;                                  // x space between elements
    int yMarge = 10;                                  // y space between elements
    int elementWidth  = 35;                            // Size of element
    int elementHeight = 35;
    CGPoint topLeftPos = CGPointMake(10, 10); // Top left position of first element

 for (int i = 0 ; i < maxElements ; i++)
    {

        int row = [[[SeatArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"row"] intValue];
        int column = [[[SeatArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"column"] intValue];

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake((xMarge + elementWidth) * column + topLeftPos.x,
                                  (yMarge + elementHeight) * row + topLeftPos.y,
                                  elementWidth,
                                  elementHeight);

        UIButton *v = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        v.frame = frame;

        [v setTitle:[[SeatArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        v.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT size:10];
        [v setTitleColor:Sky_Colour forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        int  length     =  [[[SeatArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"length"] intValue];
        BOOL available  =  [[[SeatArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"available"] boolValue];
        BOOL ladiesSeat =  [[[SeatArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"ladiesSeat"] boolValue];

        if(length == 2)
        {
            if(available == NO)
            {
                [v setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [v setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Doublebedgray"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else if (ladiesSeat == YES)
            {
                [v setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoublebedPink"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else
            {
                [v setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Doublebed"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(available == NO)
            {
                [v setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [v setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SingleSeatGray"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else if (ladiesSeat == YES)
            {
                [v setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SingleSeatPink"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else
            {
                [v setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SingleSeat"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }

        v.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;

        v.tag = i;

        [v addTarget:self action:@selector(Seats:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.view addSubview:v];


    }
```